# While working on worksheet events in Excel vba Inputbox is not working and remaining cells other than intersect I could not update color also

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, excel-2010

I am getting error of "the cell or chat you are trying to change is on a protected sheet. To make a change, unprotect the sheet" but I gave input box for getting password from user such that automatically cells will be unlocked but why I am getting this error

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim X As Range
    Dim Pass As String
    Pass = "Kals"
    Set X = Union(Range("I3:I9"), Range("K3:K9"))
    If Not Application.Intersect(Target, X) Is Nothing Then
        ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:=LCase(Pass)
        If Target = "" Then    
        ElseIf Target <> "" Then
            Pass = InputBox("Enter value", "Enter password")
            Target.Locked = True
            ActiveSheet.Protect Password:=LCase(Pass)
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Which line is the error on ?

Comment: Because the cell you are trying to edit is protected. That code won't solve anything if you are trying to change a protected cell. You can't change a protected cell, therefore the change event can't be triggered, therefore the macro will not run in the first place. What's yor overall objective?

Comment: I just want to lock only that cell  once I entered  data on that cell and if that cell is blank means I can enter data on that cell, consider if I want to change the data on that cell then I have to enter password which should be poped up and user have to feed the password and if that password matches with orginal password means I can change the data which is already locked, I tried with Input box for already locked cell to change data on it but that Input box pop us is not working at all instead I'm getting error of cell is already locked

Comment: manually unprotect your sheet first then select your ranges `I3:I9` `K3:K9` right click then select `Formal Cells` then on `Protection` tab uncheck `Locked` then protect your sheet with the same password in your code, make sure to allow select unlocked cells, then you can test the  worsheet change event

Comment: That one is okay, my need is I have locked the cell after I have entered the data on cells which were empty but now I have to change data on locked cell for that I should not go to Excel sheet and enter password instead while I'm trying to change the data there itself one pop up (Input box) should come there I have to type the password, if that password matches then no sheet should be unprotected and cells should be unlocked. First need is automatically cells should be freezed once I entered data on empty cell, second need is if I want to change the data on locked cells then pop up should come

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Const Pass = "Kals"
    Dim v
    With Application
        If .Intersect(Range("I3:I9,K3:K9"), Target) Is Nothing Then
           Exit Sub
        End If
        
        ' new value
        v = Target.Value
       
        ' undo change to get old value
        .EnableEvents = False
        .Undo
        ' check if change allowed
        If Target.Cells.Count = 1 Then
            ' was it blank
            If Target.Value = "" Then
                ' replace "" without pasword
                Target.Value = v
            ElseIf Pass = InputBox("Enter password", "Enter password") Then
                ' password correct enter new value in cell
                Target.Value = v
            Else
                ' incorrect password
                MsgBox "Password incorrect, no change made", vbExclamation
            End If
        Else
            MsgBox "Change 1 cell only", vbExclamation
        End If
        .EnableEvents = True
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: That is really working but user should not add color to cell already entered, color function should also be locked once the user entered the data